# 'Open In Excel' option is grayed out for .xlsm files in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, excel, office-web-apps, office-integration

We know that excel files with macros and password protections are not supported to view in Browser using Office Web App / Excel Web App. In this SharePoint shows small dialogue where it has 'Open In Excel' option. However, in our case for some documents this option is grayed out and for some of them its working as expected (Open In Excel option not grayed out). Please find following screenshot. 'Open In EXcel' button is grayed out.

[image: error_Open In Excel]

Is there any limitations on Office Web Apps / Excel web app that we can only x number of macros / password protected sheet or x number of rows of data with password / macros? What is the best way to enable the Open in Excel option for this scenario on Excel Office Web App / Office Web Apps integrated with SharePoint 2013 environment?

Comment: Have you checked the settings in the Document Library>Advanced Settings>Opening Documents in the Browser ?

Comment: @Tally yes.  i have already checked this setting and 'Opening Documents in the Browser' is selected. my Issue is, for some .xlsm files 'Open in Excel' button is not grayed out and for some files it is grayed out.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find a solution for this. I am facing same issue, I know sheet is protected (which is intended) but the open in excel is shown grayed out. Any solution to make the button work?

Comment: @Unnie, sorry but No luck.. we are still facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in error screen, i think those files are password protected or might be macro enabled file.. in online only limited feature supports

For checking is it password protected, download that excel file and Go to file and info, there you can see is it protected or non protected.

[image]

Comment: Yes Thivasagar, I know these files are password protected. but for other macro enabled files 'Open in Excel' button is enabled. but for some of them it is Disabled(grayed out). I am not able to identify the issue as it is behaving differently for different password protected macro enabled files. for Example,I have 2 files in my 'Test ' library. file1.xlsm and file2.xlsm. for file1.xlsm 'Open in Excel' button is enabled and for file2.xlsm 'Open in Excel' button is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IE? Per my test,  open in excel would be enabled in IE.

Try to add the site in compatibility mode.

Try to add the site into trust site.

Comment: Yes. I am using IE 11. Already did. On same site and same library, Its behaving differently for 2 documents.